# Is it possible if I change the location of file and namespace will automatic change?

Tags: php, namespaces, phpstorm, sublimetext3

I am currently using Sublime & PhpStorm. I don't have much experience in Sublime, but in PhpStorm if I will create new file in folder, it will automatically create class and namespace of that file. So what if I move file to another folder and it will change namespace according to it.

Is that any feature or package available for this functionality?

I already tried F6 for Reflactor | Move, but maybe I am doing something wrong, here is the screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

as you can see, using F6 file is moved but namespace is still same.

Comment: I believe it’s already in as part of [Refactor | Move](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/move-refactorings.html) functionality

Comment: @DanielProtopopov can you see my updated question

Comment: Hmm, I have tested that by setting Sources as app folder instead of root of my Laravel application, and for some reason it didn't work when I try to do as per documentation. Perhaps, someone else can comment what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

PhpStrom has feature to refactor code

Refer: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/refactoring-source-code.html

So once you rename or move class it will update namespace and class both

Comment: I tried that, can you please see my updated question